# What is the origin of "cross country skiing"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, american-english

I was speaking of skiing when I was in USA, and I discovered that one type of ski is called *cross country skiing*.

What is the origin of that phrase, which is not really referring to skiing through countries?

Comment: There are two completely different types of skiiing.  "Nordic" aka "Langlauf" aka "cross-country" is done on trails made for the purpose on flat ground (in the "open countryside").  Your heel is not attached to the skis.  "Downhill" aka "Alpine" skiing is done using ski-lifts and a mountain.   The two are totally unrelated.  (They are as different as say hiking and gymnastics; there is utterly no connection in equipment or technique.)

Comment: You will also find "cross country running", "cross country flights" etc., none of which are necessarily between countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cross-country) gives the following elucidating definition:

> also cross country, crosscountry; 1767, of roads, from cross (v.) + country, or aphetic for across-country. Of flights, from 1909.

i.e. It does not refer to movement across borders of countries, but rather *across* a single country (at some scale).

So, "cross-country skiing" can basically be interpreted as "skiing across [significant] terrain". Specifically, it does of course involve a very specific technique, different to that of downhill skiing. Analogies can be made with "cross-country running" as well.

Comment: And specific skis, boots and bindings as well

Comment: "but rather across a single country"  utterly incorrect.  "country" in the sense of "countryside", not "a nation".

Comment: Note however that "cross-country running" is absolutely, completely, identical to any other running.  Alpine skiing and Nordic skiing are as different as, say, surfing versus canoeing, or bowling versus darts.

Comment: @JoeBlow You misinterpret my answer. Read the next paragraph.

Answer (score 7):

It's using the term [cross-country](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cross-country) not in the sense of national boundaries, but open countryside. Basically, it means skiing through fields, pastures, open range, whatever. It is contrasted with *downhill* skiing in which skiers follow a (usually) prepared track down a mountainside.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the origin of that phrase, which is not really referring to skiing through countries?

The phrase isn't referring to a *political* country, but country in the sense of the "outdoors" -- the rural area outside of cities and towns. It is the same sense as such phrases as *country roads*, *back country*, *Country and Western* music, etc.

*Cross-country skiing* refers to skiing which historically took place across significant stretches of rural landscape, rather than up and down one hill or mountain (*downhill skiing*). The phrase has been applied to this technique of skiing even if it takes place on a well-groomed city track or trail.

Answer (score 1):

**Cross-Country** as an adjective has two meanings. Here it means "**Taking place outside roads**"

Examples:

> **Cross-country running**
>
> **Cross-country Skiing**
>
> We took a **cross-country route** instead of the motorway.

Also check this [link](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cross-country).

Comment: It has no connection at all to "outside roads".  There is downhill or mountainside skiiing which takes place on mountainsides.  (Using a particular type of equipment, and, ski-lifts.)  There is langlauf, "countryside" or "open country" skiing which takes place on open flat countryside.  (Using totally different equipment, and no ski-lifts.)  99% of langlauf is on carefully prepared roads or trails for the purpose. (Indeed, 99% of downhill skiiing is on carefully prepared trails (on the side of a mountain) for that purpose).